# how to check object is exits or not in view ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I have implemented query on distant lat long and create virtual field in query like this

```
user        = User.all
if longitude.present? && latitude.present? && fulladdress.present?

   distantQuery = "(3959 * acos( cos( radians("+latitude+") ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians("+longitude+")) + sin( radians("+latitude +")) * sin(radians(latitude))))  < " + miles
   user = User.select("*, (3959 * acos(cos(radians("+latitude+")) * cos( radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians("+longitude+")) + sin(radians(" +latitude +")) * sin(radians(latitude))))  as distant").where(distantQuery)
end
```

when my if condition run then distant is coming other wise it will not coming

```
<% @result.each do |r| %>
<tr>
<td>
 <%= r.distant.present %>

</td>
</tr>
```

now in view my distant is come form query then it will show result and when it will not come then it show me error

```
undefined method `distant' for #<User:0x000000092a6558>
```

I have implement "present" in view

```
  <% if r.distant.present? %>
                        <%= r.distant.to_i %>   


                <% end %>
```

but still it show me error, What will i use to check if distant is coming then it will show and other wise not ?

Answer (score 5):

this should work:

```
 <% if r.respond_to?(:distant) %>
```

however this is too much logic in the view, i suggest you refactor some of your code to have very simple and safe methods in your view

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%= r.try(:distant) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use another approach:

```
user =  if longitude.present? && latitude.present? && fulladdress.present?
          distantQuery = QUERY_BODY_HERE
          User.select(SELECT_QUERY_HERE).where(distantQuery)
        else
          User.all
        end

unless user.respond_to(:distant)
  class << user
    def distant ; nil ; end
  end
end
```

The advantage of this approach is that you have consistent `User` class, responding to `#distant` correctly regardless of whether it was calculated.